# urllib.request not found in .py code

Tags: windows, python-3.x, urllib

I'm working with Python 3.4 on Windows:
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

At the Python command line, everything works fine (no errors):

*>>> import urllib.request*
*>>>*

Then I write the following single-line code test.py:

```
import urllib.request
```

If I execute test.py I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\user\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

I tried various things (obviously unsuccessfully!), so I'm absolutely baffled. Can anyone give me a clue??...

Comment: Spot on J.F. Sebastian!... It appears I have a "rogue" Python27 install on my computer (which was used to execute the code instead of 3.4). I've used your link to redirect the .py files to Python 3.4. Problem fixed! Thanks! (can I flag your comment as answer?...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Make sure that you run the script using Python 3 interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) e.g., configure your system to use Python launcher `py` and add the appropriate shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) in your Python script.